# Add text to video using ffmpeg command working in mac but give error in ubuntu?

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am running below ffmpeg command that is working fine in mac but in ubuntu give error:

> [aac @ 0x15187a0] The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.

**Command:**

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=FutuMd.ttf: text="Audi": x=680: y=500: fontsize=55: fontcolor=white: enable='between(t,4,6)'" introfinal.mp4
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg. The AAC encoder hasn't been marked as experimental since Dec 2015.

Comment: @Gyan thank you now command is working.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the aac encoder for ubuntu is **experimental** and not enabled by default. So you should use `-strict -2` argument to enable it manually.

Change your command to:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -strict -2 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=FutuMd.ttf: text="Audi": x=680: y=500: fontsize=55: fontcolor=white: enable='between(t,4,6)'" introfinal.mp4
```